# Where do I adjust the auto logout duration for administrators?

Tags: permissions

This is my first time asking a question about CiviCRM and am not sure if I am even in the right place.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  This is the perfect place to ask CiviCRM questions.  This just so happens to not be a CiviCRM question, but that's not at all obvious to most folks.  As Andy mentions, this is one of the relatively few places where Civi defers to the CMS.

Answer (score 1):

User access is done by CMS so it isn't really a Civi question. If you are on WP, you can use this https://wordpress.org/plugins/inactive-logout/. If other CMS, post on their forum.